# Самодельный Model View Controller

Tags: php, mvc, инспекция-кода

Изучаю php OOP пару недель, сделал структуру MVC с роутером.

https://github.com/versinsk/mymvc

Есть ли уязвимости в этом сайте и как хорошо/плохо написан код?
За основу брал много роутеров, уделял внимание на строгую проверку названия контроллера и метода с массивом шаблонов.

P.s. Жду любой критики, для меня это очень важно.

Comment: Там же только скелет. Напишите сайт средней сложности и тогда сами поймёте минусы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас модель это свойство контроллера. А если нужно будет в одном экшене работать с несколькими моделями? Зачем фабрика, к тому же дальше в контроллере вы обращаетесь к статике по имени.
2. Namespace'ы и  Autoloader классов. (Кстати именования классов бы под один стандарт свести. А то где-то с маленькой где-то с большой)
3. Роутер не динамический. Допустим вам нужно добавить новый экшен. Вы создаете его в контроллере и потом прописываете еще в папке сomponents/router (что тоже как-то не наглядно, может переименовать в config, а то это явно не компонент)
4. Я бы избавился от ROOT. К тому же не вижу смысла обьявлять ее в index

Ну а вообще тут не особо есть на что смотреть.

Представьте просто как вы будете делать

- Разграничение ролей
- Подключать другие компоненты
- Переносить ваш MVC в другой проект, сервер, папку
- Если параметры в экшене будут в произвольном порядке
- Если у вас будут модули (с вложенными MVC), с 1000-й экшенов
- Если кто-то будет адаптировать ваш MVC под свои нужды, без правок вашего кода.
- Разные форматы Resoponse (json, html)
- Если MVC будет обвесом над какой-то уже готовой системой, и в случае если роутинг не отработал, чтоб код продолжал выполняться дальше.
- Event вроде beforeAction, afterAction
- Как модель будет работать с компонентом БД?

Comment: Спасибо учту, на счет динамического роутера, я специально создавал массив из шаблонов, чтобы искать по заготовленным шаблонам. Потом можно просто удалить шаблон, тем самым выключить какую-то страницу, а не удалять екшн, который может быть понадобиться потом.